# CLLocationManager in iOS8 waiting till user Allow or Don't Allow

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

doing current location using

> CLLocationManager in iOS8

but when it ask for the permission to user, till user select his choice the main thread is not waiting.

i tried

```
 if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {

       // [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              [self.locationManager performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
            });
    }

   [self.locationManager performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startUpdatingLocation) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

but its blocking main thread....

**how can i wait until user selects his choice...?**

Comment: The method `requestAlwaysAuthorization ` is assign, thus you can not wait for it. It will call the delegate with the choice the user made.

Comment: When you ask for permission then cllocation delegate is called didChangeAuthorizationStatus there you can check the status of authorization and implement -startupdatinglocation

Comment: thanks all... i solved that problem, by using delegate method